# Ubuntu 22.04 Neovim init.vim set mouse not working

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, neovim

I'm currently using Ubuntu 22.04, nvim v0.6.1.

I've created an nvim config file called `init.vim` located at `~/.config/nvim`. Using the `nvim -V` command, I can see that the `init.vim` file is successfully being sourced. In the file, I only have one line of code: `set mouse=a`. When I try opening a file with nvim, the mouse clicks do not work initially. Only when I manually type `:set mouse=a` and enter after opening the file with nvim does mouse clicking work.

Although my default terminal is Alacritty, I have tested this with the default terminal as well, with the same results. I've tried adding a colon at the front of the line in the `init.vim` file as well, and have tried switching to `init.lua`.

Why does it work when I manually type it in the terminal, but not with the init files?